# How to convert the position in CGDisplayBounds() to global coordinate ( like NSEvent.mouseLocation) in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm a newbie in Swift and MacOS.
I gonna find a method to get the exact display coordinate

```
NSEvent.mouseLocation
```

[image]

I have found method in CoreGraphic :

```
func CGDisplayBounds(_ display: CGDirectDisplayID) -> CGRect
```

but the coordinate is different.

[image]

I can workaround to apply a method to mathematically method to convert point Y.
But is there any method to get or convert the position programmatically?

**I expect to get the same coordinate with NSEvent.mouseLocation.**

Thank for your attention.

It returns to the same coordinate with mouse location.

Comment: Well, haven't you answered your own question? On Mac, core graphics coordinates are flipped so you have to apply a transform.

Comment: I have found another solution: NSScreen.screens.map{ OSXScreenDelegate(nsScreen: $0) } and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, CoreGraphics has what Apple calls ‘flipped’ geometry, with the origin at the top left and the y coordinates increasing toward the bottom of the screen. This is the geometry used by most computer graphics systems.

AppKit prefers what Apple calls ‘non-flipped’, with the origin at the bottom left and the y coordinates increasing toward the top of the screen. This is the geometry normally used in mathematics.

The origin (0, 0) of the CoreGraphics global geometry is always at the top-left of the ‘main’ display (identified by `CGMainDisplayID()`). The origin of the AppKit global geometry is always at the bottom-left of the main display. To convert between the two geometries, subtract your y coordinate from the height of the main display.

That is:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func convertedToAppKit() -> CGPoint {
        return .init(
            x: x,
            y: CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID()).height - y
        )
    }

    func convertedToCoreGraphics() -> CGPoint {
        return .init(
            x: x,
            y: CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID()).height - y
        )
    }
}
```

You may notice that these two functions have the same implementation. You don't really need two functions; you can just use one. It converts in both directions.

Calling `CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID())` might also be inefficient. You might want to cache the value or batch your transformations if you're going to be doing a lot of them. But if you cache the value, you'll want to subscribe to `NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification` so you can update the cached value if it needs to change.

Comment: Thank for your explanation! I have tried your suggestion before and it will got some mismatch when there is 2 or more connected monitors ( of course with the different position as on top or bottom). Hence, I have tried to map the NSScreen to Appkit coordinate and its works totally.